# How to make a for loop return filler lines when it can't reach a predetermined number?

Tags: python

I am scraping `n` iterations of the same type of data from 'a, b, c, d' sources, but sometimes one of these data sources will return less than `n` values because it does not have that much to pull from (for example I will set `limit=5`, but `c` will only have 3 values to scrape from).

The problem is that I am organizing the returned data in lists by skipping every `n`th value, so it messes up the pattern if one of these don't return at least an empty filler line when it cannot pull anything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please post the code that you have tried and the output that you are receiving? It would be helpful to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Write a "wrapper" function that calls the scraper function and checks the length of the value it returns, and if there aren't enough, adds those missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a wrapper for the generator that guarantees a result, even if that result is `None`:

```py
def get_result(source, fillvalue=None):
    return next(source, fillvalue)

>>> iterator = iter([1, 2, 3])
>>> [get_result(iterator) for _ in range(5)]
[1, 2, 3, None, None]
```

Alternatively, pass your chunk of 5 results through a function that enforces length

```py
def enforce_length(n):
    def wrapped(lst):
        for _ in range(n):
            yield next(lst, None)

    return wrapped

enforce_length_5 = enforce_length(5)

>>> list(enforce_length_5([1, 2, 3]))
[1, 2, 3, None, None]
```

However it's likely that there's a better solution that could be had by reorganizing your code a little.